# Django single code, 2 configs/2customers (2 different databases)

Tags: django

I'd like to have a scenario:

- I've got django application for some purpose for example "restaurant app"
- I'd like to serve it to one customer (so have specific database and django settings)
- and then i'd like to use the same code (code+css+images etc) (not duplicate it in separate folder), and just use additional settings and database, to serve it to the second  customer
  etc.

Any ideas how to do it?
(so , in case some code changes, I will not need to change code for all customers)

Comment: You could either deploy one instance of your app per customer, or look into multitenancy libraries for Django.

Comment: Ok thanks, the "multitenancy" was the keyword I was looking for. Now I can do more google research. Thanks again. Some first result: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/index.html